# Batch insert mode with hibernate and oracle: seems to be dropping back to slow mode silently

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to get a batch insert working with Hibernate into Oracle, according to what i've read here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html , but with my benchmarking it doesn't seem any faster than before.

Can anyone suggest a way to prove whether hibernate is using batch mode or not? I hear that there are numerous reasons why it may silently drop into normal mode (eg associations and generated ids) so is there some way to find out why it has gone non-batch?

My hibernate.cfg.xml contains this line which i believe is all i need to enable batch mode:

```
<property name="jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
```

My insert code looks like this:

```
List<LogEntry> entries = ..a list of 100 LogEntry data classes...
Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
for(LogEntry e : entries) {
  sess.save(e);
}
sess.flush();
sess.clear();
```

My 'logentry' class has no associations, the only interesting field is the id:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="log_entries")
public class LogEntry {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  public Long id;
  ..other fields - strings and ints...
```

However, since it is oracle, i believe the @GeneratedValue will use the [sequence generator](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernateidgeneratorelement.shtml). And i believe that only the 'identity' generator will stop bulk inserts.

So if anyone can explain why it isn't running in batch mode, or how i can find out for sure if it is or isn't in batch mode, or find out why hibernate is silently dropping back to slow mode, i'd be most grateful.

Thanks

Comment: The docs you linked recommend flushing as often as you hit a batch size. You could try that.

How many records are you inserting? Only 100? That may not be a big enough number to actually see a performance improvement.

Comment: I'm inserting 250000 records all up. I'm batching them into arrays of 100 and then passing them to my DAO (the insert code above). So i am flushing and clearing each 100 rows.

Comment: I changed log4j to output debug level logs, and saw this "AbstractBatcher  - Executing batch size: 96" - does this mean my batching is working?

Answer (score 2):

> (...) but with my benchmarking it doesn't seem any faster than before.

Before what? What are you measuring? What did you change? How are we supposed to guess that?

> Can anyone suggest a way to prove whether hibernate is using batch mode or not?

Activate logging in DEBUG mode, the `o.h.j.BatchingBatcher` class - which is an implementation of the `Batcher` interface that actually uses batching - logs entries like this:

```
log.debug( "Executing batch size: " + batchSize );
```

---

You should maybe consider using the `StatelessSession` instead.

Comment: In Hibernate v4, you can now find this at `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch`

Answer (score 1):

If jdbc meta is disabled using:

```
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults
```

then no jdbc batching is performed. This is the case in hibernate 3.3.2.GA.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to go to log4j and enable debug level logging, then look for the:

```
AbstractBatcher - Executing batch size: *
```

line in thelog/console. In my case, it *was* running in batch mode, it's just that Hibernate is really slow!

Answer (score 0):

You were not seing a performance improvement because:

From: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm

> "The Oracle implementation of standard update batching does not
>   implement true batching for generic statements and callable
>   statements. Even though Oracle JDBC supports the use of standard
>   batching for Statement and CallableStatement objects, you are unlikely
>   to see performance improvement."

And if you turn on oracles own batching, it breaks hibernate because update counts don't work.  At least that's what I found.